# Transparent PNG in Weebly landing page

Tags: css

I am building an information website for a client who is hosting an MUN in their school. I'm using Weebly for this because the client wants to be able to control their data themselves, so they need an easy interface. On the homepage, I have used the landing-page format to have the MUN logo float over a background image.

[image: The logo remains stationary while the background scrolls behind it.]

As you can see, there's an ugly white background in the logo. I attempted to fix this by editing the JPG in PS, removing the background and saving as PNG. I then uploaded the PNG:

[image: Transparent PNG]

and wrote it into the website's CSS like so:

```
.landing-page #banner {
    padding: 0;
}

#bannerleft {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}

.landing-page .wsite-header {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

However, despite the image being a PNG with a transparent background, the image on the website still had a white background. The slight changes in the image were apparent, so I knew that the chosen PNG had been rendered, but yet the background remained the same. I suspect it has something to do with the container behind the image showing through.

**How can I make the background image show through the logo using PNG transparency?**

Comment: have you checked that the .png really has a transparent background? Do you have any link to the page and/or image?

Comment: Edited question with image.

Comment: the image is certainly transparent. I just made a simple test loading the image with the img tag and as background with CSS and everything works as expected. Have you checked that the loaded image on the page is the one you want? may be it's being replaced by another version (not png) for some reason. I've see that happening, but it was time ago, the .png files where replaced by .jpeg files for compatibility. Although that shouldn't be happening now.

Comment: That's exactly what my question is about, whether Weebly converts to JPG, and if so, how can I circumvent it.

Comment: first check if that is what is happening. Use any of the many tools to check, or the source code viewer of your browser, or the media tab when you ask for the information of the page on firefox. If that is what is happening, change that image for a gif. But first confirm what is happening.